# How to convert Object and view it on WebAPI?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my question, 
I got a Web API and client(winform), client will send out data with a Serialize Object. My Web API do have received and return a response to client. But I can't view the data on Web API, I do have try using Deserialize Object and convert it into string but not working neither.
Please help me,Thanks!

Here is my code:

Client

```
 private string WebApiPost(string sParam, string sJson)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(sJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync(sWebAPI_URL + sParam, content).Result;
        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return body;
    }
```

This is my Web API

```
public object Post([FromBody]object hL7)
    {

        //what should I do???
        //I've tried set hL7 into string but it wont get any data;
        //I've also tried deserialize it but will get 500 internal server error.
        return hL7;
    }
```

This is my WebAPI model

```
public class HL7MID
{
    public string LOC { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY { get; set; }
}

public class HL7MID_List
{
    public string sMSG { get; set; }
    public List<HL7MID> data = new List<HL7MID>();
}
```

Comment: Does the shape of the json that you are posting to your service look like your models of your API? If so, change the `hL7` object type to that type. I try to avoid using the type `object` like the plague.

Comment: I don't see any wrong things in your code. Maybe your content of `sJson` is not correct or could not be parsed into `HL7MID`.

Comment: @NathanWerry I am not sure what you are talking about, what you mean about shape of json?

Comment: What does sJson look like? We do not know what your input is.

Comment: @KhaiNguyen I think you are right ! The error code keep showing error converting value, but my sJson content is same as class HL7MID

Comment: @Fin Can you pass `string sJson` sample on your post?

Comment: @KhaiNguyen yes , it can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sJson` matches `HL7MID`, you can use that type in as a paramter of your `Post` function, and just use that type.

```
public HL7MID Post([FromBody]HL7MID hL7)
{
    //use hL7 here
    return hL7;//also since you know the return type, changing that to HL7MID is suggested
}
```

Comment: OMG! It is working!! But there is still got a weird stuff. The value return by hl7 is null

Comment: Please ellaborate, where is it null?

Comment: Guys! I found the problem and solved it! I realize that the type value after serialize is different with the data type of deserialize!